# Find Next Select Selected Value

Tags: jquery, select, text

I've got a very simple table with multiple rows. The first two cells in each row have a select drop down list.

Using jQuery I'm read through each row and I want to get the text value from each select.

But this only returns the text value of the first select, not the second one as well.

```js
$(".test").each(function() {
  thisSelected = (this.options[this.selectedIndex].innerHTML)
  text = $(this).closest('td').next().attr('.update');
  console.log(thisSelected + ' -> ' + text);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<tr id="rows">
  <td>
    <select name="test[]" class="test">
      <option value="0"></option>
      <option value="1">Home</option>
      <option value="2">Away</option>
     </select>
  </td>
  <td>
    <select name="view[]" class="view">
      <option value="1">Yes</option>
      <option value="0">No</option>
     </select>
  </td>
  <td>
    <img src="clear.png" class="rm" name="rm" title="clear">
  </td>
</tr>


<tr id="rows">
  <td>
    <select name="test[]" class="test">
      <option value="0"></option>
      <option value="1">Home</option>
      <option value="2">Away</option>
     </select>
  </td>
  <td>
    <select name="view[]" class="view">
      <option value="1">Yes</option>
      <option value="0">No</option>
     </select>
  </td>
  <td>
    <img src="clear.png" class="rm" name="rm" title="clear">
  </td>
</tr>

<tr id="rows">
  <td>
    <select name="test[]" class="test">
      <option value="0"></option>
      <option value="1">Home</option>
      <option value="2">Away</option>
     </select>
  </td>
  <td>
    <select name="view[]" class="view">
      <option value="1">Yes</option>
      <option value="0">No</option>
     </select>
  </td>
  <td>
    <img src="clear.png" class="rm" name="rm" title="clear">
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: When should this happen? When any select changes? When the form is submitted? BTW, IDs **must** be unique

Comment: Hi. Sorry this example is showing with the selects empty. I'm running this as jquery when the page actually has selected values. I'm validating the form so there won't be any empty selections.